# Nest.js: handle multiple file processing using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

While developing on a 'clean' node.js frameworks, like Express.js - we can just easily handle file processing, callbacks, validations etc. But using Nest.js -> it's becoming simpler for simple issues, but more complex when you want to tune it...

I want to upload multiple files on the server, and right after that call another service action (like processing data from files async etc). Nest.js is using multer for this. And I got stuck...

```
import { Controller, HttpException, HttpStatus, Post, UploadedFiles, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AnyFilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';
import { extname } from 'path';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

@Controller('reader')
export class ReaderController {
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(
        AnyFilesInterceptor({
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: './uploads',
                fileSize: 5e7,
                files: 20,
                filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                    try {
                        const fileName = uuid();
                        return cb(null, `${fileName}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
                    } catch (err) {
                        return cb(new HttpException('Errored at upload', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
                    }
                }
            }),
            fileFilter: (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
                if (file.mimetype.match(/\/(png)$/)) {
                    cb(null, true);
                } else {
                    cb(
                        new HttpException(
                            `Unsupported file type ${extname(file.originalname)}`,
                            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
                        ),
                        false
                    );
                }
            }
        })
    )
    uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files) {
        console.log('files', files); // <--- here
    }
}
```

How can I on my upload success action (or not success) handle it? How can i handle async file upload status? Like first file was uploaded with OK/NOK status and proceed with other files here (I will need to emit Socket action with 'file#n was uploaded with OK status')?

Normally I will just write something similar:

```
async.each(req.files, function(file, callback) {
  saveFile(file, file.name, callback)
}, function(err) {
  res.send('')
})
```